# Find or create an NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

In one of my `NSManagedObject` subclasses I want to have `findOrCreateByExternalId:inContext:` class method. It is surely simple, except for saving the context. Here can be a number of variants in case of creation:

1. let the caller save the context as necessary;
2. save the context synchronously;
3. save the context asynchronously.

And the last (but not the least?) variant:

- decouple *find* from *create* and this way force the caller to manage the context.

I think that the 1st is too bad because of the overhead on the caller side and the 3rd is too bad because of possible unpredictable results.

Synchronous save seems to be the most safe approach, but I should save only newly created object and not the whole provided context.

For now my solution is like so (using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)):

```
+ (instancetype)findOrCreateWithExternalId:(NSString *)externId inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    XXObj *obj = [XXObj MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"externId" withValue:externId inContext:context];
    if (obj == nil) {
        __block XXObj *newObj = nil;
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            newObj = [XXObj MR_createEntityInContext:context];
            newObj.externId = externId;
        }];
        obj = [newObj MR_inContext:context];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Does this approach seems reasonable and safe?

Comment: *"...I should save only newly created object and not the whole provided context."* That's not possible. You can save a MOC or not save it, but you can't save individual objects in a MOC.

Comment: What if I will create a new context with one new object and save it, then fetch that object in the original context? This is what I think is done in my code snippet.